# Select current is not equal to 1 from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please see the records on my table below.

```
id employer current
-- -------  -------
1  IBM       0
1  Infosys   0
2  Microsoft 1
2  Google    0
3  Facebook  1
```

I want to get the list of `id` which `current` is `0` for all rows as follows

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
id employer current
-- -------  -------
1  IBM       0
1  Infosys   0
```

I built a query as follows; but is there a one line solution for this ? Please help me.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_work where id NOT IN ( select id from tb_work  where current = '1' )
```

Comment: Google should be in the result too, or am i missing something?

Comment: Probably he wants to get those IDs only which have current = 0 for all records sharing the same ID. @Yazan

Comment: yes, may be, just figured it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_work t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM tb_work t2
                  WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.current = 1)
```

Comment: why the sub query and join? just use `current != 1` ?

Comment: @Yazan No, this wouldn't be correct. The OP wants to select `id`s being related *exclusively* to 0.

Comment: ahh, sorry, now i got, that's why Google not included in OP result sample, because ID 2 had a record with current=1 (microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

you are making it somehow complex, if you do paper work, you will see the right solution within your work. like

```
   SELECT * FROM [tb_work] WHERE current = '0'
```

why you are using "NOT IN" clause and sub-query to make it complex? make it simple.

Comment: Please see the output i wanted. Your query doesn't meet the requirement.